# get rid of square brackets in java

Tags: java

I am writing a program in SWI-prolog and Java.

My problem is, when i print the result from prolog in returns with `[]` and I don't want this.

The code for printing the results is

```
String t8 = "findDiseases(" + mylist + ",Diseases)."+ "\n";
Query q8 = new Query(t8);

Diagnosis_txt.append("Με τις δοθείσες πληροφορίες πάσχετε από: " +
                     "\n" + 
                     "\n" +
                     q8.oneSolution().get("Diseases"));
while (q8.hasMoreSolutions()) {
    Map<String, Term> s7 = q8.nextSolution();
    System.out.println("Answer is " + s7.get("Diseases"));          
}
```

And the printed results is

```
Answer is '[|]'(drepanocytocis, '[|]'(drepanocytocis, '[]'))
```

I want to get rid of this `[|]` and the `[]`. I want to print only `drepanocytocis`.

Comment: what is the return type of `s7.get()` ?

Comment: Which occurrence of `drepanocytocis` are you looking for?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indent the code in a readable way.

Comment: @LutzHorn the code is largely irrelevant to the question anyway - it is simply how "some value" is obtained, but the problem is how to process that value once you have it. I'd propose removing it.

Comment: The return of s7.get() is this in blockquote

Comment: @DebbieMp but there are two occurrences of `drepanocytocis` in that string. Where is the data that you want to obtain located in general?

Comment: There are in a prolog code file...The problem of two occurences is from prolog.. i am trying to solve this now...

Comment: @DebbieMp there's not much point in asking a question about how to solve a problem if you're just going to change the problem before you get an answer.

Comment: No i am not going to change this problem...this problem still exists..
The changes i make in prolog code doesn't make any changes in this..
The only change is that only one occurrence must be shown but still with brackets...

Comment: I don't know....I assume an empty list...but it doesn't make sense..
In prolog the answer is **Diseases = [drepanocytocis, drepanocytocis].**

Comment: The expected result is **[drepanocytocis,drepanocytocis]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to remove all special characters you can do something like this:

```
answer = answer.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+", "").trim();
```

**update**

to remove any duplicate spaces after that run, the full solution can do somthing like this:

```
answer.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+", " ")
    // remove duplicate spaces
    .replaceAll("[ ]([ ]+)", " ")
    // remove leading & trailing spaces
    .trim();
```

It can then be split on spaces to get the correct sanitized answer...

However, as @andy suggested, I recommend finding the source of the data, and building a proper data structure for it to return exactly what you want. post processing should only kinda be used for data you have no control of, or old versions, etc...

Comment: Won't this result in `drepanocytocisdrepanocytocis`?

Comment: more like, `drepanocytocis        drepanocytocis`, but another pass can remove double spaces :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the space. Still - not what OP asked for.

Comment: The double reasult of drepanocytocis is prolog problem (i am trying to fix right now) the only problem in java was this with brackets..Just a minute to try the asnwer of epoch.

Comment: Surely `"[ ]([ ]+)"` would be more easily written as `" {2,}"`?

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes it can, its going slow today ;)